# How can I determine which flashlights have the maximum regulated output for the longest duration?

Tags: flashlights

Googling `brightest flashlight 2019` doesn't help, as third-party websites and manufacturers' websites don't exhibit the  maximum regulated output for the longest duration. [This website](https://www.wellrigged.com/worlds-brightest-flashlights/) does for some flashlights, but it overlooks the [Imalent MS12](https://redd.it/ci10kl). My family'll be spending at least £200, so we mustn't overlook other headlights or be hoodwinked!

Comment: Why would you spend that much on a flashlight when the one for £5 is just as good for most needs?

Comment: It's pretty rare that you need much above about the brightness of say car headlights (max around 12000 lumens I think). What purpose do you have for the lights - how big an area are you trying to illuminate and for how long? How portable do you need it to be?

Comment: @bob1 I'd be using the flashlight to illuminate hiking trails, bicycle  and off-road driving trails with no other cars or lights. I don't mind paying more for more lumens.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. I nearly deleted as spam as flagged, but thought I'd give the benefit of the doubt. That said, the questions you are asking on this topic are not in scope here.

Answer (score 1):

As you are looking for a range of different purposes. There is no one-size-fits-all here.

I have a basic (headlamp) one from Black Diamond that will illuminate up to 80 meters (260 feet) with a max of 300 lumen output. This is plenty to see trails for hiking, running, climbing, camping etc. There are many options to choose from in this range. Your local outdoors shop likely stocks around 20 different ones. Even a 100 lm one is adequate for basic needs. These are usually very light and easily transportable, and have great running time - about 25 h range on high setting and up to about 200 h on low (11 m/35', plenty for around a campsite). These usually run on AAA batteries or similar.

Bike lights go up to about 5000 lm, which is incredibly bright (about 4x brighter than halogens on car headlights). If you are say, a down-hill mountain biker in competition, you might want one of these, but otherwise you can go for much dimmer ones without compromise. These come with the trade-off in that they are large, heavy and consequently not so transportable. They are not designed to be carried by hand, but clamped to the bike. They also only tend to have about 2-3 h run time and then require recharging (2-13 h according to article I found [here](https://www.bicycling.com/bikes-gear/a25222841/best-mountain-bike-lights/)).

Vehicles should have their own lights, and there are very few situations where you couldn't mount lights on a vehicle to run off the internal power supply that would be more than adequate for off-roading, even on the darkest of trails on a rainy night.